# Does eOS support separate light and dark desktop backgrounds?

Tags: settings, desktop, wallpaper

I was poking around in dconf and noticed that `io.elementary.desktop.background` has a setting called `dim-wallpaper-in-dark-style`. By default it is off. However, enabling it doesn't seem to do anything, even when dark theme is turned on in System Settings → Desktop → Appearance.

Also, in `org.gnome.desktop.background` there are two settings for the background image: `picture-uri` and `picture-uri-dark`. By default `picture-uri-dark` is set to `'file:///usr/share/backgrounds/gnome/adwaita-d.jpg'`, which doesn't exist in elementary OS. Changing it to a file that *does* exist, e. g. /usr/backgrounds/odin-dark.jpg, doesn't do anything—the wallpaper doesn't change if dark theme is on.

Is it possible to get the wallpaper to change automatically when the OS is in dark mode, using either of these settings (or something else)?

Comment: Did you try Switcher from AppCenter? https://github.com/JeysonFlores/switcher

Comment: I didn't know about that app, thanks! It would be nice to have the ability built-in, but Switcher works perfectly fine in the meanwhile.